# Oracle Coalesce returns blank

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

I have following query which uses coalesce to return the id of a calendar with a specific code

```
 SELECT COALESCE(SD_CALENDAR.ID,0) FROM SD_CALENDAR WHERE SD_CALENDAR.CODE = 'BOER';
```

But when I run this I get a blank column as result, instead of 0. What do I need to change to make my query work?

Comment: Then `ID` is not `null` but a blank string. Change the data type of the column to a number like `int`

Comment: Or there are not rows in the table. Depends on what blank colimn means

Comment: There are +- 30 rows in the table, but none matches this query.

Comment: @juergend: there is no such thing as a "blank string" (`''`) in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I assumed that Juergen meant that the string contained blank characters, e.g.: `' '`

Comment: "none matches this query" - you mean you have no rows with code 'BOER', and you get no data returned rater than a row with a null expression value? When there are matches will there be multiple results, or is the code column unique? And is ID even nullable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that no rows in your table match your query, so you are trying to return 0 when there is no match, rather than returning no data at all.

If `NAME` is unique then you could use an aggregate to achieve this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(SD_CALENDAR.ID),0) FROM SD_CALENDAR WHERE SD_CALENDAR.CODE = 'BOER';
```

The `MAX()` will always return one row; if there is a match it will be the single ID anyway, and if there isn't it will be null - which you can then coalesce to zero.

If `NAME` isn't unique and you expect multiple values back then you can use a union to provide the zero value when there is no match:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SD_CALENDAR.ID,0) FROM SD_CALENDAR WHERE SD_CALENDAR.CODE = 'BOER'
UNION ALL
SELECT 0 FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT COALESCE(SD_CALENDAR.ID,0) FROM SD_CALENDAR WHERE SD_CALENDAR.CODE = 'BOER'
);
```

Depending on what you're doing, it might be better/easier to let your application handle a no-data-found result and substitute a zero itself.